# How to check with latest row in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to check if the user's otp code is correct.

My User_Otp table is structured as below.

id | code | user_id | created_at | updated_at

Sample Data is:

id | code | user_id | created_at | updated_at

19 | 1234 | 27      | 10:12:26   | 10:12:26

20 | 1235 | 27      | 10:12:27   | 10:12:27

21 | 1236 | 27      | 10:12:28   | 10:12:28

I want to only allow user verified when he enter `1236` as otp code because it is the latest code as he tried to resend otp code.

I used below code to achieve this but not working:

```
$userOtp = UserOtp::where('code', request('code'))->where('user_id', request('user_id'))->latest('created_at')->first();
if ($userOtp) {
    // verified
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `latest` function does only order the result, not filter. This means you will always get a result if the code exists, you could do something like this:

```php
$userOtp = UserOtp::where('user_id', request('user_id'))->latest('created_at')->first();
if ($userOtp->code === request('code')) {
    // verified
}
```